# I just hired a new programmer should I limit his access in any way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket

I started working for a startup a while ago and they ask me to hire a new programmer, so I did. Then my boss asked me to limit his access, in case something happens.How should I limit his access to repos, AWS, etc? Can I do this in a non evasive way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming *per se,* more about employee management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) is your friend. A new-to-the-company programmer probably only needs access to certain repositories and certain AWS services.

With AWS that means using IAM and granting permissions to what is needed- for instance, perhaps read-only access to all S3 and EC2 areas. See AWS's documentation on [least privilege access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAMBestPractices.html#grant-least-privilege).

On the other hand, you hired an engineer because you trust them, and limiting access from necessary resources is expensive. It depends on the person's role- if she is a devops person, she probably needs deep access. If he is a junior engineer who hasn't used AWS before, very limited access would make sense.